# Codeigniter Database Error Number 1048 Values show NULL even though they are NOT NULL

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have situation where codeigniter shows database Error Number 1048. It seems Values NULL but when I try to check it usign **var_dump($_POST)** Values are not NULL.

**Controller : Jurusan.php**

```
public function simpan()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('code','Kode','required|integer');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('jurusan','Jurusan','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('singkatan','Singkatan','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('ketua','Ketua','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nik','NIK','required|integer');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('akreditasi','Akreditasi','required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $isi['content'] = 'jurusan/form_tambahjurusan';
        $isi['judul'] = 'Master';
        $isi['sub_judul'] = 'Tambah Jurusan';
        $this->load->view('tampilan_home',$isi);
    } else {
        $this->model_security->getSecurity();

        $key = $this->input->post('code');
        $data['kd_prodi'] = $this->input->post['code'];
        $data['prodi'] = $this->input->post['jurusan'];
        $data['singkat'] = $this->input->post['singkatan'];
        $data['ketua_prodi'] = $this->input->post['ketua'];
        $data['nik'] = $this->input->post['nik'];
        $data['akreditasi'] = $this->input->post['akreditasi'];

        $this->load->model('model_jurusan');
        $query = $this->model_jurusan->getdata($key);

        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            $this->model_jurusan->getupdate($key,$data);
        } else {
            $this->model_jurusan->getinsert($data);
        }

        redirect('jurusan');
    }   
}
```

**Model : model_jurusan.php**

```
class Model_jurusan extends CI_model {
    public function getdata($key)
    {
        $this->db->where('kd_prodi',$key);
        $hasil = $this->db->get('prodi');
        return $hasil;
    }

    public function getupdate($key,$data)
    {
        $this->db->where('kd_prodi',$key);
        $this->db->update('prodi',$data);
    }

    public function getinsert($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('prodi',$data);
    }
}
```

**Here is the error shown :**

[image]

**Here is the database structure :**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong syntax in these lines:

```
$key = $this->input->post('code');
$data['kd_prodi'] = $this->input->post['code']; // <-- use ('code')
$data['prodi'] = $this->input->post['jurusan']; // <-- use ('jurusan')
```

---

Change this to

```
$this->input->post['array_key'];
```

this

```
$this->input->post('array_key');
```

---

Read : [Input Class in Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#using-post-get-cookie-or-server-data)

Comment: what is array_key ? i still don't get it. i thought that i should set ** _input name form_ ** inside `$this->input->post['  ']`

Comment: i already using input_form_name in this case.but the output still NULL

Comment: The issue is not the name you are using, but you misuse the "[ ]" with "( )". In this line you are already did the right things `$key = $this->input->post('code');` but the next line you use `$data['kd_prodi'] = $this->input->post['code'];`. The "[ ]" means you are accessing the array key of an **array**, while `$this->input->post` is actually a **method** that accept string as parameter. So, a method use "( )" `$this->input->post('blabla')`, **not** "[ ]" `$this->input->post['blabla']`.

Comment: thanks . finally i realize that. but after i change the code like your advice, still can't insert data into database. and i still can't figure what's wrong with my code.

Comment: finally, i figure out what's wrong. thanks for your help. @JMS786

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem lies in your way of accepting input parameters.

```
$this->input->post
```

is a method which accepts the variable name, not an array. So all the input parameters need to be passed as a function parameter to post method. These lines need to be altered to.

```
$data['kd_prodi'] = $this->input->post('code');
$data['prodi'] = $this->input->post('jurusan');
$data['singkat'] = $this->input->post('singkatan');
$data['ketua_prodi'] = $this->input->post('ketua');
$data['nik'] = $this->input->post('nik');
$data['akreditasi'] = $this->input->post('akreditasi');
```

Hope this solves the problem.

EDIT:

You did a `var_dump($_POST)` which works as it is supposed to and it will read the values of the post parameters. So either you fetch the parameters from `$_POST` array, or you use the `$this->input->post()` method. But I would suggest using the `$this->input->post()` method as it provides additional sanitization such as xss attack handling etc, which could be turned on an off from the config.

Comment: still can't figure out the error cz still can not insert data into database.

Comment: finally, i figure out what's wrong. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

i have tried your code...it works. I think there some mistakes in your `<input>` tags, You must use `<input name="">` not `<input id="">` or something else. Hope it can help you out

Answer (score 0):

You are try to get value from post is wrong. You should use at this way

```
    $_POST['array value'];
```