# Codeigniter database error number 1048 it shows column cannot be null

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have situation where codeigniter shows database Error Number 1048.It seems Values NULL but when I checklist the checkbox null in phpmyadmin it works it can go to the web, but when I want to submit name, the name not appear just blank. Please help me I'm confused.

This is the controller:

```
<?php

class Invoice extends CI_Controller{
    public function index()
    {
        $data['invoice'] = $this->model_invoice->tampil_data();
        $this->load->view('templates_admin/header');
        $this->load->view('templates_admin/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('admin/invoice',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates_admin/footer');
    }
}
```

This is the model class:

```
<?php

class Model_invoice extends CI_Model{
    public function index()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
        $nama   = $this->input->post('nama');
        $alamat = $this->input->post('alamat');

        $invoice = array(
            'nama'         => $nama,
            'alamat'       => $alamat,
            'tgl_pesan'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'batas_bayar'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(date('H'), date('i'), date('s'), date('m'), date('d') + 1, date('Y'))),
        );
        $this->db->insert('tb_invoice', $invoice);
        $id_invoice = $this->db->insert_id();

        foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item){
            $data = array(
                'id_invoice' => $id_invoice,
                'id_brg'     => $item['id'],
                'nama_brg'   => $item['name'],
                'jumlah'     => $item['qty'],
                'harga'      => $item['price'],
            );
            $this->db->insert('tb_pesanan', $data);
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    public function tampil_data()
    {
        $result = $this->db->get('tb_invoice');
        if($result->num_rows() > 0){
            return $result->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYbTO.png)

Please help me fix what I've tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codeigniter Database Error Number 1048 Values show NULL even though they are NOT NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384393/codeigniter-database-error-number-1048-values-show-null-even-though-they-are-not)